# Bootstrap4 Stacking Cards

Tags: bootstrap-4

New to bootstrap and I am trying to learn how to stack cards.  I have the following code:

```
<div id="home">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-title">Card 1</div>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, idque summo intellegam his ea, fugit deserunt has ei. Magna minimum prodesset id ius, pri te adhuc officiis evertitur, vel nulla comprehensam ne. Ad prima accumsan conceptam vis, per at augue paulo constituto. Quo evertitur dissentiunt et, ut verterem lobortis mei. Minimum fabellas similique eu eam, ea his simul quaeque consetetur...</p>
                <div class="btn-cntr"><button class="float right">Read More...</button></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-title">Card 2</div>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, idque summo intellegam his ea, fugit deserunt has ei. Magna minimum prodesset id ius, pri te adhuc officiis evertitur, vel nulla comprehensam ne. Ad prima accumsan conceptam vis, per at augue paulo constituto. Quo evertitur dissentiunt et, ut verterem lobortis mei. Minimum fabellas similique eu eam, ea his simul quaeque consetetur...</p>
                <div class="btn-cntr"><button class="float right">Read More...</button></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-title">Card 3</div>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, idque summo intellegam his ea, fugit deserunt has ei. Magna minimum prodesset id ius, pri te adhuc officiis evertitur, vel nulla comprehensam ne. Ad prima accumsan conceptam vis, per at augue paulo constituto. Quo evertitur dissentiunt et, ut verterem lobortis mei. Minimum fabellas similique eu eam, ea his simul quaeque consetetur...</p>
                <div class="btn-cntr"><button class="float right">Read More...</button></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-title">Card 4</div>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, idque summo intellegam his ea, fugit deserunt has ei. Magna minimum prodesset id ius, pri te adhuc officiis evertitur, vel nulla comprehensam ne. Ad prima accumsan conceptam vis, per at augue paulo constituto. Quo evertitur dissentiunt et, ut verterem lobortis mei. Minimum fabellas similique eu eam, ea his simul quaeque consetetur...</p>
                <div class="btn-cntr"><button class="float right">Read More...</button></div>
            </div>                      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

which produces 3 cards on one row and a single card on the second row.
I am looking to establish 4 cards on a single row (lg), 2 cards on one row and 2 cards on the second row (md) and finally single cards stacked on top  of each other (sm).

When I resize my browser, I notice the the cards resize as well and I need the cards to remain the same size and stack accordingly as the screen resizes.  Need some help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use this for each column:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card">
           ..
      </div>
</div>
```

**Demo:** https://www.codeply.com/go/nnBMQjZA3R

**How it works:**

- `col-lg-3` - use 3/12 on lg and up
- `col-md-6` - use 6/12 on md
- (below md cols will stack and become full-width)

---

Alternately, you could use the auto-layout cols on `lg` since `col-*` will evenly fill the row...

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg"></div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly; however, putting the tablet in landscape mode changes the size of the cards (makes them tall and skinny) and puts them all on one row.  The width of the tablet in portrait is 1024px.

Comment: It answers your question: *"4 cards on a single row (lg), 2 cards on one row and 2 cards on the second row (md) and finally single cards stacked on top of each other (sm)"* The md breakpoint is 992px so "4 cards on a single row (lg)" won't stack to 2 rows until 992px.. that's just how Bootstrap works.

Comment: Thanks, Zim...still learing all the column classes, etc.

Comment: Hmm. Thought I did.  Sorry about that.  Thanks, again, for your help.

Comment: Zim, you have been a great help.  May I contact you for a quick question that I am certain you would have an answer for?